# How pass JSON value to PHP and store in Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

Now i m having json values like this in `json_obj` variable in `javascript`, now i need to pass this value on `submit` and have to store in `mysql`. i dont know how to pass json to same page on submit and store in `php`

```
var json_obj = [
    {"id":"1","name":"munna","salary":"20000"},
    {"id":"2","name":"selva","salary":"30000"},
    {"id":"3","name":"ashok","salary":"12000"}
]
```

This json_obj value will change dynamically each time ( 4 rows , 6 rows etc.., )

Comment: You can POST JSON just like you can post any other data.

Comment: Storing JSONs (or any serialized data) in the database whiffs a little of bad database design to me... why not just create the extra tables to store the data in something resembling normal form?

Comment: There's no JSON there. That's just an array of objects.

Comment: Can't you narrow this down a bit? Divide and conquer! You've named four distinct technologies and don't seem to have made headway with any of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could start by encoding the object and storing it in a form field (JavaScript):

`var input = document.getElementById("someInputField");
input.value = JSON.stringify(json_obj);`

*This is assuming you have an input with id 'someInputField' that has a name and is contained within your form*. You could also make the input type "hidden".

On the server side, presuming you used POST in your form method, you could get your object by (PHP):

`$posted_object = json_decode($_POST['inputName']);`

This *should* work, but as others have mentioned, you should definitely take great care to sanitise the data to ensure that there is no possibility of injections or other security issues. Never assume that the data will always arrive in the expected format.

Comment: $posted_object = array();
   $posted_object = json_decode($_POST ['munna_test']);
   print_r($posted_object);

Answer (score 0):

use any ajax handler to send request to server, with your data, then use php function json_decode($_POST['your_object_name']); and then process it as you need

Answer (score 0):

you can post json like post any other. In php, you can use json_decode($_POST[$var]) to transfer it to object or use json_decode($_POST[$var], true) tp transfer it to array